# How can we get unlisted playlist using youtube api

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am working with youtube API but i'm not able to get unlisted playlist from my  channel and even i set mine parameter to true and its throwing me error

Comment: welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You should always include the code you are having a problem with and any error messages it is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my unlisted playlist using the API explorer. You need to authorize requests using OAuth 2.0, you can't do it with just an API key.

Comment: You can get an unlisted playlist and unlisted videos by using the `playlistItems` endpoint using just an API key.

Comment: Curious what I'm doing wrong in API explorer, since I am using OAuth flow but am being rejected when trying to submit forMine=true (same for just the standard search list API, not including unlisted videos).